# Tracking Application Install Referral With APK

Tags: android

I have an application using which anyone can share the apk of the app itself. The APK will be generated using `PackageManager` class like this:

```
File file = new File(packageManager
      .getApplicationInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
      .publicSourceDir
)
```

I need to track (deep link or some other way), who installs the app and who sent the referral? At first, it seemed infeasible to me. Then I came to know that chinese apps like Helo and WeLike actually do so. I gave it a try.
When we share the application from inside of it (have no idea how they generate APK, but the method is probably the same since I have checked they are not getting the APK from remote server and APK size is 40 MB and App Size is 40 MB so they mustn't be storing the APK in the package itself), the person who installs that APK is given the referral prize and relevant information like who referred is shown.
How is this possible? I would like to know any possible way.

In short, how can I track APK installs just with an APK file and no link (but includes generating APK from app ofcourse).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library

Comment: for tracking of apk installs (who referred and who installed) you need to that in backend server which connects to db. not on Android. you may need to send info from apk to your backend.

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram Definitely but how can I add the referral info to the created APK so that upon installation, I can retrieve the info. The APK is being created using PackageManager class which gives APK file by providing package names

Comment: it depends on how your are generating the APK for the purpose of sharing. So if you can share the logic how you are generating the APK, it can be useful to find the mechanism for tracking

Comment: @Alok Seems true but any input how I can generate this to have desired functionality?

Comment: As far as who installs the app can be tracked easily, for the purpose of tracking the referral you have to update the APK with the user identifier, may be referral id, can be placed in some kind of asset, or you can download and save the modified version of APK from the server once app installed in background that can be used for direct sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Help and WeLike are doing it.
But it seems what you are looking for is Firebase invites, which has been deprecated but firebase dynamic links should have the same functionality (as mentioned in the firebase invite page).

Comment: As I stated I don't have a link to share but I am sending the APK file directly which I need to track.

Answer (score 1):

I think most easiest solution to share the APK is by downloading the modified(including the user specific referral tacking code) version of the APK in background, once ready then user can share the version easily without waiting for it.

1. So you can say, user have the app installed.
2. user use the app normally, meanwhile you can download the modified APK with 
   user identifier
3. Once downloaded, the APK can be shared any number of times with the user 
   tracking.

Alternatively you can prepare the APK within the App, that may take more effort and complexity.